# ScrollMagic Tween: play animation only once going forward

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollmagic

I want to know how you have the animation only play once going forward when you scroll down and when you scroll up there is no animation.

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

var tween_1 = TweenMax.to('#obj_1', 0.5, {
    left: '0%', delay: .1
});

var containerScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: '#scene_1',
    offset: -100
})
.setTween(tween_1)
.addIndicators()
.addTo(controller);
```

Answer (score 12):

It's pretty easy actually, you set `reverse:false` as option, like so:

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

var tween_1 = TweenMax.to('#obj_1', 0.5, {
     left: '0%', delay: .1
});

var containerScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
     triggerElement: '#scene_1',
     offset: -100,
     reverse:false
})
.setTween(tween_1)
.addIndicators()
.addTo(controller);
```